# Мой хост пингуют? DDOS?

Tags: сеть, wireshark

заглянул в вайршарк и увидел кучу ICMP пакетов, где получатель мой локальный серый айпи 192.168.1.150.
Так же куча и tcp udp пакетов.
возможно ли, что это мальварь?

### Что это?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это твоя машина стучится ко всем на порты, а все отвечают, что пакету на данный порт не пройти... могу предположить, что у тебя просто какой-то p2p-клиент работает... возможно также, что маршруты как-то криво настроены или провайдер режет часть твоего трафика... ну а может действительно малварь завелась...

Comment: @Fat-Zer    возможно это просто торрент?

Comment: да, я так и сказал, что это какое-то p2p...